# Merging 2 results into 1 using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

in a bit of a pickle, I have a complex query which returns 2 results which is fine and dandy, but I want to modify the query so it merges the 2 and returns 1 result. I'm wondering if this is at all possible. The example I have:

```
SELECT s.f_Name s.l_Name, t.tour_Name, o.order_Placed, s.staff_ID, t.tour_ID, d.date
        FROM Staff_Day AS d, Tour as t, Staff AS s, Customers AS c
        JOIN Orders AS o ON c.customer_ID = o.order_No
        WHERE c.date >= '2014-03-18 00:00:00' AND c.date <= '2014-03-19 23:59:59'
        AND d.tour_ID = c.trip_Taken
        AND t.tour_ID = d.tour_ID
        AND d.date = c.date
        AND d.staff_ID = s.staff_ID
        ORDER BY d.staff_ID ASC
```

This returns the 2 results:

[image]

I want to merge it into 1 results so it have the following columns:

```
f_Name1, l_Name1, f_Name2, l_Name2, tour_Name,
order_Placed1, order_Placed2, staff_ID1, staff_ID2,
tour_ID1, tour_ID2, staff_Day_Date1, staff_Dat_Date2
```

Comment: on what database are you running this?

Comment: It's probably better to process the two rows in PHP to create the data you're looking for. The SQL gets messy very quickly if you need to deal with more than two rows.

Comment: Will the two rows have something in common?  You could join the table on itself (or double it up as a sub-select) and get something shaped like what you're after.  I do a similar query on our tables for stock trades, and join a single Trade table on itself to get both the buy and sell details in single row.  But I agree that this doesn't work for an arbitrary n-number of joins.

Comment: I know what you mean @user113215 but when I come to display it on my page using a while loop, I have 2 rows when I only need one! I just need to display the date, the 2 staff members and the tour taken.

Comment: Yes I understand @Danny. I might give that a shot. My SQL querying isn't top knotch obviously haha! To me it's a matter of mixing and matching

Comment: @AkiraDawson It may be better to do multiple, smaller queries. For example, one query to get the tour info, another to get the list of staff members (even if this list "always" contains two names), etc.

Comment: Using MySQL @ErwinBrandstetter if that's what you mean. still getting a grasp on SQL lol

Comment: @user113215 I have contemplated that, i'm currently drawing out on paper to see if it's doable!

Comment: @AkiraDawson You could also process the above result set as an array. For example, `$staff[ $row['tour_Name'] ][] = $row['f_Name'] . ' ' . $row['l_Name']` will give an you something like `$staff["Northern Exposure"] = array(0 => "Baz Luhrman", 1 => "Akira2 Dawson2")` which is easy to work with.

Comment: I think you're onto something @user113215 I like that, that actually seems doable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do this in MySQL. **But**...

You do **not** want to do this.

This would be better to handled in the procedural logic of PHP. Fetch the two rows, and then assemble them into the required output.

As a demonstration that it is possible in MySQL:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM ( SELECT @prev_fee           AS fee_r1
              , @prev_fee := s.fee  AS fee_r2
              , @prev_fi            AS fi_r1
              , @prev_fi  := s.fi   AS fi_r2
              , @prev_fo            AS fo_r1
              , @prev_fo  := s.fo   AS fo_r2
           FROM (
                  SELECT 'a' AS fee, '1' AS fi, 'apple' AS fo
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'c','3','cat'
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'e','5','egg'
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'b','2','bad'
                  ORDER BY 1
                ) s
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT @prev_fee := NULL
                       , @prev_fi  := NULL
                       , @prev_fo  := NULL
                ) i
          LIMIT 2
       ) t
 LIMIT 1,1
```

Your original query would replace the inline view query aliased as `s`. You'd need to define user variables for each column returned by your query, and use those to "save" the values from the previous row.

In the inline view aliased as `t`, the saved values from the previous row will need appear in the SELECT list before the user variable is set to the value from the current row. If you need to reorder the columns, you would need to do that in the outermost query.